# how to benchmark zonal and enterprise GCP Filestore?

Tags: google-cloud-filestore

In their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/performance) GCP stated that benchmarking using fio tool is not recommended for zonal and enterprise instances, any idea why and how we can achieve a benchmark of these tiers?